# PyDub Cannot Find mp3 file (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have the following code that is giving errors when trying to find the mp3 file. The link is accurate (the copyfile function is working just fine), which leads me to believe that it's a PATH issue or ffmpeg. Any ideas what's driving this?

Code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import pydub
from shutil import copyfile

pydub.AudioSegment.ffmpeg = r"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
pydub.AudioSegment.converter = r"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

copyfile(link, link2)
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(link)
second_half = sound[:30]
second_half.export(file2, format="mp3")
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\Python\Accelerators\Zillow.py", line 12, in <module>
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(link)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

cmd

```
C:\>ffmpeg
'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -codecs
ffmpeg version n4.4.1-20211101 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers <------WORKS
```

PATH:

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Is the `ffmpeg` directory added to your `PATH` variable? If so, why did you specify the path to the `ffmpeg.exe` binary manually in your code?

Comment: I thought I needed to do both - but you are right, the ffmpeg directory is in PATH